# How can I establish a Range of cells within a Worksheet to which the following code applies? As currently written it applies to the entire Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

How can I establish a Range of cells within a Worksheet to which the following code applies? As currently written it applies to the entire Worksheet.[image]

Comment: please do not submit code as a photo, instead insert it as text and format it as code.  If you are unable to format it as code correctly just insert it as text and someone will edit it correctly.

Comment: `If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:B10")) Is Nothing Then`. Change the `A1:B10` as needed.